# How to convert Azure cookie AppServiceAuthSession to a valid OAuth JWT access token?

Tags: javascript, azure, cookies, oauth-2.0, jwt

In Azure I have an App Service which hosts an SPA and ASP.NET Core WebAPI.

[Azure App Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykQjV.png)

I have activated Authentication

[Authentication active in App Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33qgb.png)

When I try to access the SPA I am first direct to a login page

[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AMrW.png)

After logging in a cookie (`AppServiceAuthSession`) is set.

[Cookie 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB0He.png)

[Cookie 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/186UH.png)

The WebAPI uses the middleware `app.UseAuthentication();` and `[Authorize]` to protect the API.

Before the SPA calls the WebAPI I convert the cookie (`AppServiceAuthSession`) to an OAuth access token using

```
https://my-app-service.azurewebsites.net/api/values
```

This does return what looks like an access_token.

[Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HjZ3.png)

```
[{
        "access_token": "PAQABAAAAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH85B5eMV5PaPELRI_hsnIMx2_pQkgf_TZr-9Z_OC26BOyQqoFM2fR...",
        "id_token": "...",
        "provider_name": "aad",
        "refresh_token": "AQABAAAAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH8k6pCkZIL4QZzJa06T0AYngu8K2WJV...",
        "user_claims": [{
                "typ": "aud",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "iss",
                "val": "https:\/\/sts.windows.net\/...\/"
            }, {
                "typ": "iat",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "nbf",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "exp",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "aio",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/claims\/authnmethodsreferences",
                "val": "pwd"
            }, {
                "typ": "c_hash",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "ipaddr",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "name",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "nonce",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/identity\/claims\/objectidentifier",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/ws\/2005\/05\/identity\/claims\/nameidentifier",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "http:\/\/schemas.microsoft.com\/identity\/claims\/tenantid",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/ws\/2005\/05\/identity\/claims\/name",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/ws\/2005\/05\/identity\/claims\/upn",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "uti",
                "val": "..."
            }, {
                "typ": "ver",
                "val": "1.0"
            }
        ],
        "user_id": "...@....onmicrosoft.com"
    }
]
```

But this token does not seem to be a JWT.

1. When using this token (in the GET header "Authorization": "Bearer ) to call the API falls with 401 unauthorized.
2. Using a decoder like jwt.io fails.
3. The refresh token is not JWT.
4. The id_token is valid.

**How do I get a valid JWT access_token from the cookie AppServiceAuthSession?**

---

**Update**
A possible solution: do not attempt to convert the cookie to an access_token. Rather do the normal OAuth2 authentication request. Azure recognizes that the user is already logged in and returns the access token (I'm using implicit flow, so the token is in the URL query string).

To trigger the normal authentication request I do

```
var url = config.authorization_endpoint
  + "?response_type=token id_token"
  + "&client_id=" + client_id
  + "&state=" + state
  + "&scope=" + requested_scopes
  + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri
  + "&nonce=" + nonce;

// Redirect to the authorization server
window.location = url;
```

---

Below is the SPA

```
var config = {
  client_id: "client_id_hash",
  redirect_uri: "https://my-app-service.azurewebsites.net/index.html",
  authorization_endpoint: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
  token_endpoint: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant-id/oauth2/v2.0/token",
  requested_scopes: "openid api://some-guid/user_impersonation"
};


function generateRandomString() {
  var array = new Uint32Array(28);
  window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
  return Array.from(array, dec => ('0' + dec.toString(16)).substr(-2)).join('');
}


function parseQueryString(string) {
  if (string == "") { return {}; }
  var segments = string.split("&").map(s => s.split("="));
  var queryString = {};
  segments.forEach(s => queryString[s[0]] = s[1]);
  return queryString;
}

function parseJwt(token) {
  try {
    // Get Token Header
    const base64HeaderUrl = token.split('.')[0];
    const base64Header = base64HeaderUrl.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
    const headerData = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Header));

    // Get Token payload and date's
    const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
    const base64 = base64Url.replace('-', '+').replace('_', '/');
    const dataJWT = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
    dataJWT.header = headerData;

    return dataJWT;
  } catch (err) {
    return false;
  }
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function component() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  const btn = document.createElement('button');

  const btnApi = document.createElement('button');
  btnApi.innerHTML = 'Call API';
  btnApi.onclick = callAPI;
  element.appendChild(btnApi);

  return element;
}

async function callAPI() {
  console.log('callAPI');
  const data = await fetchValues();
  console.log(data);
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.innerHTML = `API response: ${data.toString()}`;
  document.body.appendChild(element);
}

function fetchValues() {

  const accessToken = getCookie('access_token');
  console.log('Access token (from cookie):', accessToken);

  const url = 'https://my-app-service.azurewebsites.net/api/values';
  return fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
    }
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    });
}

(async function () {
  document.body.appendChild(component());

    const url = "https://my-app-service.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me";
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const accessToken = data[0].access_token
    const accessTokenJwt = parseJwt(accessToken);

    console.log('accessTokenJwt: ', accessToken, accessTokenJwt);

    document.cookie = "access_token=" + accessToken + "; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT;samesite";




}());
```