# How to get Azure AD access token in Static Web App?

Tags: javascript, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-static-web-app

I have a vanilla Vue.JS SWA that uses a standard Azure AD authentication via these settings in `staticwebapp.config.json`:

```json
"auth": {
    "identityProviders": {
      "azureActiveDirectory": {
        "registration": {
          "openIdIssuer": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
          "clientIdSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_ID",
          "clientSecretSettingName": "AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

An app with `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` is registered in Azure AD. Authentication is called via standard

```
/.auth/login/aad
```

endpoint. I can successfully log in and log out. "/.auth/me" endpoint returns `clientPrincipal` object with all user details (roles, id, etc) and claims.

Now I want to call MS graph API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me, but don't know how to get the access token to set the Authorization header in the request. I can see that there is a `AppServiceAuthSession` cookie is set, however it is not a token.
I have seen this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860238/how-to-convert-azure-cookie-appserviceauthsession-to-a-valid-oauth-jwt-access-to` , however reconstructing the whole auth flow looks unnecessary as I am logged in already.

Will appreciate any advice. Many thanks!

Tried to all MS Graph API as is, but as expected, got "message": "Access token is empty."
Also had a look at azure/msal-browser module in a hope to get the token silently, but it looks super complex and badly documented for a JS novice like me.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

Its look like its currently not supported see this github issue: [Add access token to user details endpoint](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/794).

Answer (score 0):

The following microsoft document shows getting the access on behalf of the user, you can refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#3-get-a-token) to get the access token.
[image: Get a token]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Methab, that will work, however my aim is to avoid using the full authorization code grant flow as a user is already signed in to Azure AD via a standard static web app process.