# Azure Static Web App authentication. Tokens and multi-tenant

Tags: azure, jwt, multi-tenant, azure-static-web-app

We have an Azure Static Web App running which has been configured with [all routes being restricted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration#restrict-access-to-entire-application).
And custom authentication is also setup [according to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad%2Cinvitations#azure-active-directory-version-2).
The associated App Registration is as follows:

- Platform: Web
- Flow: ID tokens (implicit and hybrid)
- Supported account type: multi-tenant

Logging in works fine, however, we have **two problems**:

- [/.auth/me](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/user-information?tabs=javascript#direct-access-endpoint) contains no JWT token, only the *clientPrincipal* JSON object. Unlike the same endpoint on an App Service where there is an access_token field.
  **What is then the recommended approach for passing user authentication on to the APIs that our Static Web App makes use of**? We could make use of middleware and SDKs to roll our own auth code, but we prefer to use the built-in support. We could also setup managed identities between Web App and APIs but then we would have to pass on user data as headers on the side. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71728993) is related, but if someone could explain the big-picture best-practice for authenticating to internal APIs without JWTs, then perhaps we can live without them. I have also noticed the authSession cookies, but are we supposed to get the JWT from them?
- **Users outside our AD is not able to login**, and get error **AADSTS90072** ...The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first...
  I was under the impression that having chosen multi-tenant, any valid user could log-in, and it is left up to the app developer to limit access to certain tenants if that is desired.